# raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. " django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword

Tags: python, django

I can't populate my database with dummy data. The scale of the error I got is: (raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Topic' into field. Choices are: accessrecord, date, id, name, topic_name, topic_name_id, url

Below is the codes for generating dummy data using Faker

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

# faker pop script
import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games', 'Music']

def add_topic():
t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
t.save()
return t

def populate(N=5):

for entry in range(N):

# iget the topic for the entry
top = add_topic()

# create fake data for that entry
fake_url = fakegen.url()
fake_date = fakegen.date()
fake_name = fakegen.company()

# create the new Webpage entry
webpg =
```

Webpage.objects.get_or_create(Topic=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]

```
# create fake access record for Webpage
acc_rec = 
AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]
if __name__=='__main__':
print("populating script")
populate(20)
print("populating complete!")
```

Model codes is below

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
topic_name= models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
url = models.URLField(unique=True)
date = models.DateField()
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.date)
```

Comment: show us `Webpage` model, i from what you give i believe error may be fixed by this `webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic_name =top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)`

Comment: Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic_name=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name).

Comment: have you tried suggested fix from comments? Does it work?

Comment: Yeah I tried and it is still giving me this: return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: first_app_webpage.date

Comment: @MuorditMawien but this error is completly different, so your topic is solved. Btw there is nothing about `first_app_webpage` in your question, error says that it cant be NULL, you need to pass data in this object in field `date`

Comment: @oruchkin **first_app_webpage** is coming automatically because i didn't include in the model. otherwise thank you for attending to my question

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong field name for `Webpage` object, it should be `topic_name` instead of `Topic`, so:

```
  webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic_name =top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)
```